# Compile PyGObject

Tags: python, compilation, package, fedora, pygobject

I want to create an anaconda environment with up-to-date PyGTK. So what I tried so far is:

```
conda create --name pygtk pygobject
```

This lead to the following output:

```
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - pygobject

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda pygobject
```

So I ran the search command:

```
anaconda search -t conda pygobject
```

Which resulted in:

```
anaconda search -t conda pygobject
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms      
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | ---------------
     ???/pygobject3            |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     KristanArmstrong/pygobject |   3.14.0 | conda           | win-64         
                                          : PyGObject is a Python extension module that gives clean and consistent access to the entire GNOME software platform through the use of GObject Introspection.
     fallen/pygobject          |   3.14.0 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32
                                          : PyGObject is a Python extension module that gives clean and consistent access to the entire GNOME software platform through the use of GObject Introspection.
     jeanconn/pygobject        |          | conda           | linux-64       
     jithinpr2/pygobject       |   3.14.0 | conda           | win-64         
                                          : PyGObject is a Python extension module that gives clean and consistent access to the entire GNOME software platform through the use of GObject Introspection.
     jithinpr2/pygobject3      |   3.18.2 | conda           | win-64         
                                          : Access to GObject-based libraries in Python.
     jochym/pygobject2         |   2.28.6 | conda           | linux-64       
     klauer/pygobject3         |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : Access to GObject-based libraries in Python.
     licode/pygobject3         |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     lightsource2-tag/pygobject3 |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     lightsource2-testing/pygobject3 |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     lightsource2/pygobject3   |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : Access to GObject-based libraries in Python.
     mw/pygobject2             |   2.28.6 | conda           | linux-64, linux-32, osx-64
     ostrokach/pygobject       |   3.18.2 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : PyGObject is a Python extension module that gives clean and consistent access to the entire GNOME software platform through the use of GObject Introspection.
     pkgw/pygobject3           |   3.18.2 | conda           | linux-64, osx-64
     ptorrestr/pygobject       |   3.18.2 | conda           | linux-64       
     ska/pygobject             |   2.20.0 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : Pipeline running tools
     vgauthier/pygobject       |   3.10.0 | conda           | osx-64         
                                          : Python Bindings for GLib/GObject/GIO/GTK+
     zegami/pygobject          |   3.14.0 | conda           | linux-64       
     zegami/pygobject3         |   3.12.0 | conda           | linux-64       
                                          : Access to GObject-based libraries in Python.
Found 20 packages
```

So there are many precompiled packages available, but I want to compile it myself. I think it is more trustworthy but also once I know how to do this, I can hopefully repeat that process to always use whatever version I want to use.

I created an anaconda environment with `python3.5` and nothing else. Then I downloaded the sources from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/ (3.22), extracted it, changed to its directory and tried:

```
./configure prefix=/home/user/development/anaconda3/envs/pygtk/bin/python3.5
```

According to the instructions on https://github.com/GNOME/pygobject for compilation on, everything should go smoothly, however, there is a problem with my setup:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.38.0
    gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0
) were not met:

Requested 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0' but version of gobject-introspection is 1.44.0

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GI_CFLAGS
and GI_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Then I searched using `dnf` and installed:

```
dnf install gobject-introspection
```

When I use:

```
dnf list installed gobject-introspection
```

I get the output:

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:45:43 ago on Mon Sep 26 13:56:30 2016.
Installed Packages
gobject-introspection.x86_64                                      1.44.0-1.fc22                                       @koji-override-0
```

Apparently my distro doesn't have sufficiently new packages.

How can I make progress with this now?

### Addition Infos

- OS: Fedora 22 64bit